# mybatis, the world's most popular sql mapping framework?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mybatis

[mybatis' homepage has this quote](http://www.mybatis.org/)

```
mybatis, the world's most popular sql mapping framework
```

There are only 16 questions on StackOverflow about mybatis, compared to 5,299 on hibernate. Look at Google trends. Are they completely BSing, or am I missing something (red is hibernate, blue is ibatis)?

[image]

Comment: To all closers - I'm glad @axtavt answered it. It is a real question, and can be reasonably answered in its current form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myBatis is a successor of iBatis, that's what they meant saying

> New home of the world's most popular SQL mapping framework

on their homepage. So, the name iBatis is more widely known, [ibatis](/questions/tagged/ibatis) contains 204 questions.

Also, as mentioned by duffymo, it's not an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

SQL mapping isn't the same thing as ORM.  Could be BS; could be marketing.